# How to pass states/props between components

Tags: reactjs, react-component

I have all the components listed in `App.js`. I'm kinda lost as on how to pass values from one component to the other.

Here's how it should work:

When an item is selected in the first component (`ItemList`), details are loaded in the second component (`ItemDetails`). Then in the second component if I click "add", it's added to the third component (`ItemSelection`).

How do I pass the clicked item in `ItemList` to `ItemDetails`, then pass it to `ItemSelection` on button click?

`App` component:

```
// dummy selectedItems array
let selectedItems = [
  {
    'name': 'item 3',
    'type': ['car'],
    'details': [ 'Detail 1', 'Detail 2', 'Detail 3' ]
  },
  {
    'name': 'item 6',
    'type': ['bike'],
    'details': [ 'Detail 5', 'Detail 1']
  }
]

<Container>
  <ItemList/>
  <ItemDetails/>
  <ItemSelection selected={selectedItems}/>
</Container>
```

`ItemList` component:

```
const LIST_ITEMS = require('./LIST_ITEMS.json');

const myList = 
  LIST_ITEMS.data.Items.map((Item) => (
    <li key={Item.id} onClick={() => loadItem(Item.name)}>
      {Item.name.toUpperCase()}
    </li>
  ))
;

function loadItem(name){
  console.log(name);
}

class ItemList extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <div id="item-list-wrapper">
        <h3>Select an Item</h3>
        <ul id="item-list">{myList}</ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

`ItemDetails` component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class ItemDetails extends Component {
  render() {
    <div id="item-details">
      // Additional details about the item
      <button>Add to selection</button>
    </div>
  }
}
```

`ItemSelection` component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class ItemSelection extends Component {
  render() {
    <div id="item-selection">
      // List selected items
      <h3>Selected Items</h3>
      <div className="item-slot">
        {this.props.selected[0] ? (
            <div className="selected-details">
                <h4>{this.props.selected[0].name}</h4>
                <ul>
                  <li>{this.props.selected[0].details[0]}</li>
                  <li>{this.props.selected[0].details[1]}</li>
                  <li>{this.props.selected[0].details[2]}</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        ) : (
          <p>empty</p>
        )}
    </div>
    </div>
  }
}
```

Comment: see [lifting state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I would recommend [the article, "Lifting State Up", as referenced by @codekaizer in the comments](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html).

The main principle that you want to take from the article is this

> **There should be a single "source of truth" for any data that changes in a React application.**

For your situation, that single "source of truth" should be your `App` component - the one that talks to `ItemList`, `ItemDetails`, and `ItemSelection`.

**The flow of communication between components should look like this:**

#### `ItemList`

- What items should I display? `App` will tell me in a prop.
- What should I do when one of my list items is clicked? `App` will tell me in a prop.

#### `ItemDetails`

- Which item should I display the details for? `App` will tell me in a prop
- What should I do when the "select this item" button is clicked? `App` will tell me in a prop.

#### `ItemSelection`

- What items should I display? `App` will tell me in a prop.

#### `App`

- What items should I tell `ItemList` to display? I'll pass on what I get from `LIST_ITEMS.json`
- Which item should I tell `ItemDetails` to display the details for? I'll maintain this in my `state` as `currentItem`. Initially, no item's details will be displayed.

  - If one of the items in `ItemList` is clicked, then I need to change my state's `currentItem` to be the item clicked. (HINT: `App` needs a function, and this function's callback needs to be passed to `ItemList`)
- What items should I tell `ItemSelection` to display? I'll maintain this in my `state` as `selectedItems`. Initially, there will be no items selected.

  - If the item currently shown in `ItemDetails` is "selected", then I need to add that currently displayed item to my array of `selectedItems`. (HINT: `App` needs a function, and this function's callback needs to be passed to `ItemDetails`)

---

#### Key Takeaways

- `App` should maintain a `state` with the `currentItem` to be displayed in item details and the `selectedItems` which will show up in the item selection list.
- `App` needs a few functions that manipulate the `currentItem` and the `selectedItems` states.
- `App` needs to pass those function callbacks to the children.
- The children, essentially, act as display dummies: *"Just tell me what I need to display, and tell me what I should do if someone clicks this thing over here."*

---

I've coded up a basic example of how this all looks in action. By studying it and applying it to your situation, this should give you a better understanding of how to get components to "talk to each other."

[image: Edit maintaining state between components]

Comment: Thanks a lot for this in-depth response! It helps a lot.

Comment: Is there a reason you use 'export default props' in the child components? Where does React get the component names from in your example?

Comment: By exporting it as the default, you can import the module and call it anything you want. `ItemList` himself doesn't care if the parent using him calls him `ItemList`. It doesn't matter to him. Your `App` could call the component `ListOfItems` or `ItemTable`... whatever you'd like. Here is a [helpful article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) that talks about how to use `import` and `export`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I found this article of great help too: https://programmingwithmosh.com/react/react-functional-components/